# scala iteratee to recursively process files and subdirectories

Tags: scala, loops, playframework-2.5

I want to apply a function for every file in a directory and subdirectories, as follows:

```
  def applyRecursively(dir: String, fn: (File) => Any) {
    def listAndProcess(dir: File) {
      dir.listFiles match {
        case null => out.println("exception: dir cannot be listed: " + dir.getPath); List[File]()
        case files => files.toList.sortBy(_.getName).foreach(file => {
          fn(file)
          if (!java.nio.file.Files.isSymbolicLink(file.toPath) && file.isDirectory) listAndProcess(file)
        })
      }
    }
    listAndProcess(new File(dir))
  }

  def exampleFn(file: File) { println(s"processing $file") } 

  applyRecursively(dir, exampleFn)
```

this works. the question here is how I could refactor this code by using scala Iteratees. something like this:

```
val en = Enumerator.generateM(...) // ???
val it: Iteratee[File, Unit] = Iteratee.foreach(exampleFn)
val res = en.run(it)
res.onSuccess { case x => println("DONE") }
```

Comment: Are you really looking for how to create the `Enumerator` that generates the file listing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not capture all your requirements but this can get you started

```
object ExampleEnumerator {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def exampleFn(file: File) { println(s"processing $file") }

  def listFiles(dir: File): Enumerator[File] = {
    val files = Option(dir.listFiles).toList.flatten.sortBy(_.getName)

    Enumerator(dir) andThen Enumerator(files :_*).flatMap(listFiles)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    import scala.concurrent.duration._

    val dir = "."
    val en: Enumerator[File] = listFiles(new File(dir))
    val it: Iteratee[File, Unit] = Iteratee.foreach(exampleFn)
    val res = en.run(it)
    res.onSuccess { case x => println("DONE") }

    Await.result(res, 10.seconds)
  }
}
```

Comment: waw, that's a beautiful solution!

Comment: Thanks both for your comments. @m-z I have double checked and listFiles is called when the Iteratee needs more elements. So I do not see why the entire listing should be loaded into memory. Please explain me if I am missing something.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I misread what you were passing to `Enumerator.apply`. I'll take a better look.

Comment: Thanks @m-z for taking a better look.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Enumerator.unfold` for this. The signature is:

```
def unfold[S, E](s: S)(f: (S) => Option[(S, E)])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Enumerator[E]
```

The idea is that you start with a value of type `S`, and then apply a function to it that returns an `Option[(S, E)]`. A value of `None` means the `Enumerator` has reached EOF. A `Some` contains another `S` to unfold, and the next value the `Enumerator[E]` will generate. In your example you can start with a `Array[File]` (the initial directory), take the first value from the `Array`, and check if it's a file or directory. If it's just a file, you return the tail of the `Array` with the `File` tupled together. If the `File` is a directory, you get the file listing and add it to the beginning of the `Array`. Then next steps in `unfold` will continue to process the contained files.

You end up with something like this:

```
def list(dir: File)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Enumerator[File] = {
  Enumerator.unfold(Array(dir)) { listing =>
    listing.headOption.map { file =>
      if(!java.nio.file.Files.isSymbolicLink(file.toPath) && file.isDirectory)
        (file.listFiles.sortBy(f => (f.isDirectory, f.getName)) ++ listing.tail) -> file
      else
        listing.tail -> file
    }
  }
}
```

I added an extra sort by `isDirectory` to prioritize non-directories first. This means that if directory contents are added to the `Array` to unfold, the files will be consumed first before adding more contents. This will prevent the memory footprint from quickly expanding due to the recursive nature.

If you want the directories to be removed from the final `Enumerator`, you can use `Enumeratee.filter` to do that. You'll end up with something like:

```
list(dir) &> Enumeratee.filter(!_.isDirectory) |>> Iteratee.foreach(fn)
```

Comment: wow, i still do not understand this code (the `list` function is called only once, not recursively), but it works. let me some time to study it!

Comment: cool, I understood your answer. I posted an answer with some logging to help others understand it. I wish I could mark the answer of JonasAnso and yours as accepted, but stackoverflow does not allow this; and he answered first.

Answer (score 2):

This just complements the great answer of `m-w` with some logging to help understand it.

```
$ cd /david/test
$ find .
.
./file1
./file2
./file3d
./file3d/file1
./file3d/file2
./file4
```

java:

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import java.io.File
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object ExampleEnumerator3 {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def exampleFn(file: File) { println(s"processing $file") }

  def list(dir: File): Enumerator[File] = {
    println(s"list $dir")
    val initialInput: List[File] = List(dir)
    Enumerator.unfold(initialInput) { (input: List[File]) =>
      val next: Option[(List[File], File)] = input.headOption.map { file =>
        if(file.isDirectory) {
          (file.listFiles.toList.sortBy(_.getName) ++ input.tail) -> file
        } else {
          input.tail -> file
        }
      }
      next match {
        case Some(dn) => print(s"value to unfold: $input\n  next value to unfold: ${dn._1}\n  next input: ${dn._2}\n")
        case None => print(s"value to unfold: $input\n  finished unfold\n")
      }
      next
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val dir = new File("/david/test")
    val res = list(dir).run(Iteratee.foreach(exampleFn))
    Await.result(res, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

log:

```
list /david/test
value to unfold: List(/david/test)
  next value to unfold: List(/david/test/file1, /david/test/file2, /david/test/file3d, /david/test/file4)
  next input: /david/test
processing /david/test
value to unfold: List(/david/test/file1, /david/test/file2, /david/test/file3d, /david/test/file4)
  next value to unfold: List(/david/test/file2, /david/test/file3d, /david/test/file4)
  next input: /david/test/file1
processing /david/test/file1
value to unfold: List(/david/test/file2, /david/test/file3d, /david/test/file4)
  next value to unfold: List(/david/test/file3d, /david/test/file4)
  next input: /david/test/file2
processing /david/test/file2
value to unfold: List(/david/test/file3d, /david/test/file4)
  next value to unfold: List(/david/test/file3d/file1, /david/test/file3d/file2, /david/test/file4)
  next input: /david/test/file3d
processing /david/test/file3d
value to unfold: List(/david/test/file3d/file1, /david/test/file3d/file2, /david/test/file4)
  next value to unfold: List(/david/test/file3d/file2, /david/test/file4)
  next input: /david/test/file3d/file1
processing /david/test/file3d/file1
value to unfold: List(/david/test/file3d/file2, /david/test/file4)
  next value to unfold: List(/david/test/file4)
  next input: /david/test/file3d/file2
processing /david/test/file3d/file2
value to unfold: List(/david/test/file4)
  next value to unfold: List()
  next input: /david/test/file4
processing /david/test/file4
value to unfold: List()
  finished unfold
```

Answer (score 2):

This just complements the great answer of @JonasAnso with some logging to help understand it.

```
$ cd /david/test
$ find .
.
./file1
./file2
./file3d
./file3d/file1
./file3d/file2
./file4
```

java:

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import java.io.File
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object ExampleEnumerator2b {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def exampleFn(file: File) { println(s"processing $file") }

  def listFiles(dir: File): Enumerator[File] = {
    println(s"listFiles. START: $dir")

    if (dir.isDirectory) {
      val files = dir.listFiles.toList.sortBy(_.getName)
      Enumerator(dir) andThen Enumerator(files :_*).flatMap(listFiles)
    } else {
      Enumerator(dir)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val dir = new File("/david/test2")
    val res = listFiles(dir).run(Iteratee.foreach(exampleFn))
    Await.result(res, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

log:

```
listFiles. START: /david/test
processing /david/test
listFiles. START: /david/test/file1
processing /david/test/file1
listFiles. START: /david/test/file2
processing /david/test/file2
listFiles. START: /david/test/file3d
processing /david/test/file3d
listFiles. START: /david/test/file3d/file1
processing /david/test/file3d/file1
listFiles. START: /david/test/file3d/file2
processing /david/test/file3d/file2
listFiles. START: /david/test/file4
processing /david/test/file4
```