# scala stream to recursively process files and subdirectories

Tags: scala

I want to apply a function for every file in a directory and subdirectories, as follows:

```
  def applyRecursively(dir: String, fn: (File) => Any) {
    def listAndProcess(dir: File) {
      dir.listFiles match {
        case null => out.println("exception: dir cannot be listed: " + dir.getPath); List[File]()
        case files => files.toList.sortBy(_.getName).foreach(file => {
          fn(file)
          if (file.isDirectory) listAndProcess(file)
        })
      }
    }
    listAndProcess(new File(dir))
  }

  def exampleFn(file: File) { println(s"processing $file") } 

  applyRecursively(dir, exampleFn)
```

this works. previously they [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267374/scala-iteratee-to-recursively-process-files-and-subdirectories) how to refactor this code by using scala Iteratees. The question here is how I could refactor this code by using scala Streams. 
something like this:

```
val stream: Stream[File] = ... // ???
stream.foreach(exampleFn)
```

Comment: `apply a function for every file ` - for every file, or for every file-or-subdirectory ? should `fn(file)` be called over subdirectories as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def fileStream(dir: File): Stream[File] = 
  Option(dir.listFiles).map(_.toList.sortBy(_.getName).toStream).map {
    files => files.append(files.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(fileStream))
  } getOrElse {
    println("exception: dir cannot be listed: " + dir.getPath)
    Stream.empty
  }
```

**Update**: Implementation above returns both files and directories. Here is how to exclude directories efficiently:

```
def fileStreamNoDirs(dir: File): Stream[File] = 
  Option(dir.listFiles).map(_.toList.sortBy(_.getName).toStream.partition(_.isDirectory))
    .map { case (dirs, files) =>
      files.append(dirs.flatMap(fileStreamNoDirs))
    } getOrElse {
    println("exception: dir cannot be listed: " + dir.getPath)
    Stream.empty
  }
```

However, simple `fileStream("/some/path").filterNot(_.isDirectory)` will do the same job.

**Update2**: This variant preserves the traversal order of the original example:

```
def fileStream(dir: File): Stream[File] =
  if (dir.isDirectory)
    Option(dir.listFiles)
      .map(_.toList.sortBy(_.getName).toStream.flatMap(file => file #:: fileStream(file)))
      .getOrElse {
        println("exception: dir cannot be listed: " + dir.getPath)
        Stream.empty
      }
  else Stream.empty
```

Comment: won't it include subdirectories themselves into the list of files ? Granted, the original code of the topic stater calls `fn` over directories too, but the text of his question suggests it was not his intention....

Comment: yes, i wanted to include subdirectories into the list of file, as in the code provided. sorry for the text of the question.

Comment: looks great! however, the files of the subdirectories are listed after all the siblings in the parent directory (different result from the example provided). I solved that by replacing this line, but I wonder if there is a better solution: `files => files.flatMap(file => { if (!file.isDirectory) Stream(file) else Stream(file).append(fileStream(file)) })`

Comment: @DavidPortabella, your solution is ok. Alternatively, you can move `if` "outside" and use `cons` instead of `append` (maybe a little more efficient). Actually, it works even without `if`, just prints "exception" for each file.